# find out that jQuery object really contains an existing node

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example I have following jQuery code:

```
var div1 = $("divs").next();
```

How do I find out that the div1 object really contains an existing node? For example, `$("divs1")` just had no next siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the length of the result.

```
var div1 = $("divs").next();

if ( div1.length )
  {
    //it exists..
  }
else
  {
    // no next found..
    // keep in mind that it might fail due to two reasons
    // a) no next element found
    // b) no divs element found
  }
```

You are aware that **divs** is not a valid tag name, right ? (*hope it is just an example..*)

Answer (score 3):

```
var div1 = $("divs").next();
if (div1.length != 0) {
  // valid one
}
```